# Default Values do not get applied to new versions of documents

Tags: versioning, metadata, approval-process, content-approval, default-value

Default values work correctly when a document is first uploaded to a library.  But when that document is modified and re-uploaded to the library, the default values are not applied.  I've tested this on regular default values and those put in via "Column Default Values" via Library Settings.  This library has Major and Minor versions and also requires content approval.  How do I ensure that the default values work on updated documents?

Comment: Isn't this per design though? That default values should be used when the document first get the content type of the library but that the user should be able to change them (so in your case, since you upload a new version, SP does not see this as a new document but rather one where the user has "changed" the default values to blanks)

Comment: If a user drags-and-drops a document into a library, he or she hasn't changed anything but the file itself.  I struggle to see the design benefit...

Comment: What I mean is that, it is only set on new list items, since it should be possible for users to override the values. The real problem here, if I comprehend you correct, is that these default values where added when list items already existed in the library and therefore those documents will never get the default values. Default values are just that: default values, they are not (in programmer lingo) statics

Comment: If you want values that can not be updated, but that should be set to default on every update, you could hook on a workflow or ItemUpdating event receiver to "reset" the value. If you just this once want to set the values to the default ones, you could write a PowerShell script making sure that the old document get your new default values

Comment: Thank you for the options. I'm not looking for statics; if the user purposefully changes the value, then that makes sense.  Instead, I'm just trying to get around this unintended behavior that completely defeats the purpose of document versioning.  I am using 'Column Default Settings' in the Library settings.  I have dozens of defaults and it would be difficult to also have to manage these defaults in a workflow.

Comment: When the defaults were put in place, the document library was empty...  This affects all documents in the library.

Comment: Ok, so it documents downloaded from another library in SharePoint and then uploaded in this one? You should probably clarify that in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has come to my attention that as long as a file is downloaded from SharePoint, modified and re-uploaded, the values remain the same. This issue only occurs if someone has retained the original version, made edits, and re-uploaded the changed file to SharePoint.